# REST API for uploading file inside JSON

Tags: json, rest, http, go

I am designing an REST API to upload a largish (100MB) file together with some information. So it's natural to think of json encoding.

So something like this:

```
{
   file: content of the file or URL?
   name: string
   description: string
}
```

The name and description are easy to do with json but I'm not sure how the file content can be added to it.

Also I'm thinking I should use http PUT method. Is this correct?

Incidentally, golang is used to implement this API if it matters.

Answer (score 3):

For a JSON encoding, use a `[]byte` value to hold the file contents. The standard encoding/json package encodes `[]byte` values as base64 strings.

Here's a sketch of how to implement the JSON encoding. Declare a type representing the payload:

```
type Upload struct {
    Name string
    Description string
    Content []byte
}
```

To encode the file to a request body:

```
v := Upload{Name: fileName, Description: description, Content: content}
var buf bytes.Buffer
if err := json.NewEncoder(&buf).Encode(v); err != nil {
    // handle error
}
req, err := http.NewRequest("PUT", url, &buf)
if err != nil {
   // handle error
}
resp, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)
```

To decode the from a request body on the server:

```
var v Upload
if err := json.NewDecoder(req.Body).Decode(&v); err != nil {
  // handle error
}
```

Another option is to use the [mime/multipart](http://golang.org/pkg/mime/multipart/) package. The multipart encoding will be more efficient than JSON encoding because no base64 or other text encoding of the file is required for multipart.

Comment: been trawling the internet for this simple answer. kudos to you sir.

Comment: any examples out there on how to "ACCEPT" a mime type on the server side if i send a file and a josn obj together?

Answer (score 0):

To me, the most clear-cut way to do it would be to encode the file bytes somehow.  base64 seems like a good choice, and golang has built-in support for it with "encoding/base64".